# Solve shift-reduce conlict for optional newlines in C-style block statement

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc

I want to create a grammar rule for a simplified version of a block statement in C, which matches a list of statements in braces with optional newlines at the beginning and end. Statements in this language are terminated by a newline character.

The optional newlines are so that block statements can span multiple as well as single lines. i.e, both

```
{ statement }
```

and

```
{
    statement
}
```

should be supported.

Currently my rules are as follows:

```
BlockStmt:
    '{' OptionalNewlines BlockStmtList OptionalNewlines '}';


OptionalNewlines:
        OptionalNewlines '\n'
    |   %empty;
```

Empty blocks are also supported, which are basically blocks with just newlines in them and no statements. This is possible because BlockStmtList can reduce to %empty.

However for empty blocks with just newlines, this leads to a shift-reduce conflict as the newlines can be matched by both the beginning and the ending OptionalNewlines non-terminal.

How do I tell yacc to prioritise one of the OptionalNewlines in the case of an empty block with just newlines?

Comment: Are you using newlines as statement terminators instead of semicolons? Or do you still have semicolons? If you have semicolons, why bother even passing the newlines to the parser?

Comment: forgot to clarify, I am using newlines as statement terminators

Comment: Please edit your question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a problem with blank lines in the middle of a block -- something which many of us like to do -- the simple solution is to just allow empty statements (that is, a statement consisting only of the newline terminator. If you do that, you can stop worrying about optional newlines and just use

```
BlockStmt: '{' BlockStmtList '}';
```

That's far and away the easiest. But if it doesn't work for you, read on.

In general, you cannot have a sequence of optional lists where two of the lists have the same elements. That leads to an ambiguity: if your grammar allows `a* b* a*` (using Kleene * for simplicity) and the input is `a`, there is no way to know whether the empty `a*` is before or after the empty `b*`. "Optional" elements are problematic in many situations; it's often necessary to expand empty non-terminals into multiple rules using non-optional elements:

```
BlockStmt: '{' '}'
         | '{' NewLineList '}'
         | '{' NewLineList StmtList OptionalNewLineList '}'
         | '{' StmtList OptionalNewLineList '}'
```